# Handling of multiple delegates

Tags: java, groovy, delegates

I have a java application for which I want to add an extension to execute groovy scripts. So far, so good the parsing, compiling and execution is not the problem!

For reasons of simplification I want to keep the groovy syntax as simple as possible (e.g. no OO-skills required). Furthermore, the groovy scripts shall be able to access library functions which are initialized by the java classes. This is the part where the `@Delegate` comes into play!

Currently, I came up with two different solutions which are not completely satisfying for me:

*GroovyService.java*

```
public interface GroovyService { }
```

*MyService.java*

```
public class MyService implements GroovyService {

  public static final MyService INSTANCE = new MyService();

  private MyService() { /* ... */ }

  public void method1() { /* ... */ }

  public void method2() { /* ... */ }

}
```

**Solution #1 - For each delegated method define a method shortcut**

*ServicesFacade.java*

```
public class ServicesFacade {

  public static final ServicesFacade INSTANCE = new ServicesFacade();

  @Delegate MyService myService;
  // Further @Delegate of services ...

  private ServicesFacade() { 
    myService = MyService.INSTANCE;
  }

}
```

*GroovyScript.groovy*

```
def method1 = myService.&method1
def method2 = myService.&method2

if (method1()) {
  method2()
}
```

The code part with the method shortcuts could be prepended to the string result read from the groovy file content. Without the shortcuts it would fulfill my expectations, but I'm looking for a solution for which I don't have to keep track about all the shortcuts.

**Solution #2 - Use a list of the service type and the method wildcard access**

*ServicesFacade.java*

```
public class ServicesFacade {

  public static final ServicesFacade INSTANCE = new ServicesFacade();

  @Delegate private final List<GroovyService> services = new ArrayList<>();

  private ServicesFacade() { 
    this.services.add(MyService.INSTANCE);
  }

  public void addService(GroovyService service) {
    this.services.add(service);
  }

}
```

*GroovyScript.groovy*

```
if (services*.method1()) {
  services*.method2()
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that I can use a fixed member name for any service (services*), but I'm not so impressed by the syntax.

The groovy scripts are used as follows:

```
CompilerConfiguration compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration();
compilerConfiguration.setScriptBaseClass(DelegatingScript.class.getName());
GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(compilerConfiguration);
DelegatingScript script = (DelegatingScript) groovyShell.parse(fileContent);

if (script != null) {
  script.setDelegate(ServicesFacade.INSTANCE);
  scripts.add(script);
}
/* ... */
scripts.forEach(s -> {
  s.run();
});
```

Is there a better way in achieving a direct method call of the delegated methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a good solution in which I wrote an analogous [`Script`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java) class similar to [`DelegatingScript`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/DelegatingScript.java). It looks as follows:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import groovy.lang.MissingMethodException;

import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public abstract class MultiDelegatingScript extends groovy.lang.Script {

  private final Map<Object, MetaClass> delegateMap = new HashMap<>();

  protected MultiDelegatingScript() {
    super();
  }

  protected MultiDelegatingScript(Binding binding) {
    super(binding);
  }

  public void setDelegate(Object delegate) {
    this.delegateMap.put(delegate, InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(delegate.getClass()));
  }

  @Override
  public Object invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
    for (Map.Entry<Object, MetaClass> delegate : this.delegateMap.entrySet()) {
      try {
        // Try to invoke the delegating method
        return delegate.getValue().invokeMethod(delegate.getKey(), name, args);
      } catch (MissingMethodException mme) {
        // Method not found in delegating object -> try the next one
        continue;
      }
    }

    // No delegating method found -> invoke super class method for further handling
    return super.invokeMethod(name, args);
  }

}
```

Using this class instead of *DelegatingScript* will completely fulfill my expectations!